# Close/destruct an FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, object, ftp

I would like to create a C# function in order to test a connection to an FTP Server.

**Here is my function :**

```
        FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + strHost.Trim());
        requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUser, strPass);
        requestDir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = requestDir.GetResponse();
            return "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
```

**My problem is very simple :**

I I use a good host ( a good FTP Host), my function return "OK".
If, after, i use a bad host, it return an exception

```
ERROR 421 : Service not available. Closing control connection.
```

If, **atfer, it re-test** with the good adresse, i have a new time this exception.

I need to close and re-open my application in order to solve this problem.

I try with :

```
KeepAlive = true / false and no changes.
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: Are you creating a new request on your re-test?

Comment: Yes because this function is in the code behind a "TEST" button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `FtpWebResponse` class and close it after getting you directory listing:

```
try
{
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)requestDir.GetResponse();
    string status = response.StatusDescription;
    response.Close();
    return status;
}
```

More Information in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.NET.FTPWEBREQUEST.GETRESPONSE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) 

Note:

> Multiple calls to GetResponse return the same response object; the
>   request is not reissued.

Answer (score 10):

As FtpWebResponse  implements IDisposable interface, you also could use it like this:

```
using (FtpWebResponse  ftpWebResponse = (FtpWebResponse)requestDir.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

No need to explicitly call the close method.